# Python generate more elements in pythonic for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to generate more elements in a pythonic for loop. How can I do that? The normal code is:

```
my_list = ['foo', 'bar']
li = []
for i in my_list:
    li.extend(['a_' + i, 'b_' + i])
```

So the result should be:

```
['a_foo', 'b_foo', 'a_bar', 'b_bar']
```

Thank you!

Comment: your code is working, what do you want?

Comment: As the title and my first sentence say: I want a "pythonic" solution, so I want a "one line" working code. I got it thanks to [olofom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/328258/olofom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're after but I'd write it like this:

```
foobar = ['foo', 'bar']

li = ['{}_{}'.format(y, x) for x in foobar for y in ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: Thank you everybody. I made only a little change to get exactly the same list I expect: `['{}_{}'.format(y, x) for y in ['a', 'b'] for x in foobar]`

Comment: That's what I wrote at first but then you get `['a_foo', 'a_bar', 'b_foo', 'b_bar']` instead of `['a_foo', 'b_foo', 'a_bar', 'b_bar']` as you wrote as output in your question :)

Comment: You are right, I screwed up something... Your solution is perfect!! (my comment results wrong list)

Answer (score 2):

If you had two lists you could use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from `itertools`

```
from itertools import product

l = ['foo', 'bar']
add = ['a', 'b']

['_'.join(a) for a in product(add, l)]

['a_foo', 'a_bar', 'b_foo', 'b_bar']
```

Comment: Very creative solution.

Comment: You don't need so many loops for this, `['_'.join(a) for a in product(add, l)]` produce the same output.

Comment: It is also a very excelent solution, thank you!! Maybe the order of result elements should be other: `['a_foo', 'b_foo', 'a_bar', 'b_bar']`